# My scripts and styles get served as text/html

Tags: apache, mime-types, osx-mavericks

Since the update to Mac OS Mavericks all my styles and scripts get served as `text/html`

[image: css as text/html]
[image: js as text/html]

I have no idea where I can change this behavior. I'm using the built in apache service

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that static files works as expected. The files above get parsed by a php script to get served cached and compressed. I'm using `header("Content-type: text/css")` to define the content type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further digging into the cacheing script I found a [flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) method forces PHP to add a text/html content type in the header. This happens right before I add headers like `header("Content-type: text/css")`

I've rewritten my class method and the output is now correct. Strange is that it doesn't cause the problem on my live server with the same cacheing class

Answer (score 2):

In your server/vhost config try adding:

```
AddType text/javascript .js
AddType text/css .css
```

If something else is already setting the type, you can try adding this instead:

```
<Files "*.js">
    ForceType text/javascript
</Files>

<Files "*.css">
    ForceType text/css
</Files>
```

Comment: I wrote these lines in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` but doesn't change anything